# Maximum of all subarrays of size k

Tags: c++, queue, sliding-window

PROBLEM: Given an array arr[] of size N and an integer K. Find the maximum for each and every contiguous subarray of size K.

Why doesn't the following test case pass for the code below:-

> Input:
>  5 4
>  1 2 3 4 5
>  Its Correct output is:
> 4 5
>
> And my Code's output is:
>  4 5 5

```
int find_max(queue<int> q){
    int max = 0;
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        if (q.front() > max)
            max = q.front();
        q.pop();
    }
    return max;
}
vector<int> max_of_subarrays(int *arr, int n, int k){
    // your code here
    vector<int> res;
    queue<int> q;
    vector<int> temp;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    //for cases where n = k
    if(k == n){
        sort(arr, arr+n);
        temp.push_back(arr[n-1]);
        return temp;
    }
    while(j < n)
    {
        q.push(arr[j]);
        if ((j - i + 1) < k) 
        {
            j++;
        }
        else if((j - i + 1) == k)
        {
            int x = find_max(q);
            res.push_back(x);
            //removing first entered element from queue
            q.pop();
            //pushing the next element to the queue
            q.push(arr[i]);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    //for last window
    int x = find_max(q);
    res.push_back(x);
    return res;
}
```

Can someone tell what's going wrong here?

Comment: Debugger could certainly do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can help.

The line `q.push(arr[i]);` is wrong. Index i will not be the last element. So, rather index j+1 should be used. But this will be pushed anyway in the next loop run.

So, you do not need this line at all. Delete it!

And in your while loop, you find already all results. So, you can simply delete the last 2 lines

```
    int x = find_max(q);
    res.push_back(x);
```

Then your function will work.

But for real C++ it is too complicated.

You could also use the following approach with a `````std::deque````:

```
auto maxOfContiguousSubArray(std::vector<int>& data, size_t subArraySize) {
    // Here we will store the result
    std::vector<int> result{};

    // And this will hold our subarray. We use a deque, because we will have then have required iterators
    std::deque<int> subArray{};

    // Special case: Number of elements is less or equal the subarray size
    if (data.size() <= subArraySize) {

        // Get the one max element
        result.push_back(*std::max_element(data.begin(), data.end()));
    }
    // Go over all numbers in data
    else for (size_t index{}; index < data.size(); index++) {

        // Store value in sub array
        subArray.push_back(data[index]);

        // If there are enough values in subarray, then
        if (index >= subArraySize-1 ) {
            // Get the max value
            result.push_back(*std::max_element(subArray.begin(), subArray.end()));
            // Remove the first value
            subArray.pop_front();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    
    size_t n{}, k{};

    // Read number of elements and size of subarray
    if (std::cin >> n >> k) {

        // Here we will store our numbers
        std::vector<int> data{};
        // copy n numbers from std::cin into data
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), n, std::back_inserter(data));
        // Calculate the max values
        auto max = maxOfContiguousSubArray2(data, k);
        // Show the user output
        std::copy(max.begin(), max.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

But basically, you do not need a subarray at all. You can simply build a sliding door with iterators or with indices.

Then the function would look like that:

```
auto maxOfContiguousSubArray2(std::vector<int>& data, size_t subArraySize) {
    // Here we will store the result
    std::vector<int> result{};

    // Special case: Number of elements is less or equal the subarray size
    subArraySize = std::min(data.size(), subArraySize);

    // Find the max element of the window
    for (auto first{ data.begin() }, last{ data.begin() + subArraySize-1 }; last != data.end(); ++first, ++last)
        result.push_back(*std::max_element(first, last));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood it now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem - Given an array arr[] of size N and an integer K. Find the maximum for each and every contiguous subarray of size K.

This is how "Maximum of all subarrays of size k" problem is implemented in Java

```
class Solution
```

{

```
static ArrayList <Integer> max_of_subarrays(int arr[], int n, int k)
{
   
     
     int i = 0,j = 0;
     ArrayList <Integer> ans = new ArrayList <Integer>();
     Deque<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
     while(j<n){
         
        while(q.isEmpty() == false && q.peekLast() < arr[j]) 
          q.removeLast();
                
        q.addLast(arr[j]);
       
        if(j-i+1 < k)
         j++;
         
       else if(j-i+1 == k){
           ans.add(q.peekFirst()); 
             
           if(arr[i] == q.peekFirst())
           q.removeFirst();
           i++;
           j++;
        }
         
    }
       return ans;  
    }
}
```